# Getting null from DB still ID exist in DB in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
 public function contactDetail($user_id){
        // dd($user_id);
        $details = User::get(['id','first_name','last_name','mobile_no'])->where('id',$user_id)->first();
         dd($details);
        return View::make('ContactDetail')->with('data',$details);
    }
```

`$user_id` stored value but in `$details` getting null from DB. if I use static value rather than `$user_id` getting values from DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query to:

```
 $details = DB::table('users')
              ->select('id','first_name','last_name','mobile_no')
              ->where('id',$user_id)
              ->first();
```

You are calling a where before `get()`, this must be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Yes, Thanks! I need to use `get()` after `where()`

Comment: Nice! If it worked for you, could you please accept the answer? Thank you!

Comment: sure! after 3 min.